# Text values are not reflected on dashboard on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Hello,

trying to use SonarQube 5.1 for custom measures.

Created several custom measures, including int and text values. Assigned them through custom widgets to project and was thinking the data will appear.

Specified values through web service api.

1. The values for custom measures are not appearing until you start next scan. How we can have data available immediately as meausre has some data?
2. After scan the data for integer values appear but not for text values. I see measure with text values are assigned for the project but they are not shown for the project. How to make them visible?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you analyzed since you added the metrics? Metric changes on a project only become effective at analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to this Bug  : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6203